# Date.prototype.getHours() behavior varies with region

Tags: javascript, date, google-cloud-functions

I have a date `let date1 = "2020-06-19T09:00:00+05:00"`, when I do `date1.getHours()` in my local computer(I live in Pakistan and my timezone offset is +5:00), I get `9`, which is perfectly fine. If I deploy my API to firebase function, it gives me `4`. I suspect this is because the firebase server has different timezone offset. I want it to return `9` on firebase too.

Comment: I think Date.prototype.getUTCHours() you can use this, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours, or maybe there must be a setting in firebase

Comment: You can use Moment's NPM package for timezones: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have specific requirements for handling dates and times with respect to specfic timezones, then you will have to build that into your code.  JavaScript and nodejs don't know what timezone you want, and Cloud Functions has a default timezone that can't be changed.

If you want to work with dates and times using a specific timezone, consider using a library that makes it easier, such as [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).